# getimei() giving me imei of 2nd sim slot in some andorid Devices?

Tags: android, imei, dual-sim

Sometimes, I am getting the IMEI of the **second SIM SLOT** when getting from this code :

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                    String imei = telephonyManager.getImei();

                    return imei;

                } else {

                    String imei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                    return imei;
                }
```

This is affecting the users where if their **deviceId** gets changed they will get logged out. Because of the **mismatch** in the device.

What are the chances of getting **IMEI of the second SIM** even if I am querying the IMEI of the **SIM SLOT 1**?

Answer (score 0):

static boolean handleDeviceIdDisplay(Context context, String input) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
                (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

```
    if (telephonyManager != null && input.equals(MMI_IMEI_DISPLAY)) {
        int labelResId = (telephonyManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) ?
                R.string.imei : R.string.meid;

        List<string> deviceIds = new ArrayList<string>();
        if (TelephonyManagerCompat.getPhoneCount(telephonyManager) > 1 &&
                CompatUtils.isMethodAvailable(TelephonyManagerCompat.TELEPHONY_MANAGER_CLASS,
                        "getDeviceId", Integer.TYPE)) {
            for (int slot = 0; slot < telephonyManager.getPhoneCount(); slot++) {
                String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(slot);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(deviceId)) {
                    deviceIds.add(deviceId);
                }
            }
        } else {
            deviceIds.add(telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
        }

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle(labelResId)
                .setItems(deviceIds.toArray(new String[deviceIds.size()]), null)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps